# Html - text in span tags is not inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried using the span tag to get text inline, but I think my template from which I extend is automatically blocking the text. I dont really understand much of Html so I dont really know where I should search for the setting to block all text automatically.

Here is my template where I tried using the span tag to get something inline:

```
{% extends "base_generic2.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <!-- Timer function -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var sec = 0;
    function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
    setInterval( function(){
        $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec%60));
        $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(sec/60,10)));
    }, 1000);
 </script>

<h3>C-Test</h3>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Time:<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>

{% endblock %}
```

For some reason the minutes:seconds are not inline and I dont know where the problem is in my base_generic2.html:

Here is my base_generic2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        {% load static %}
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CTEST 2</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A sidebar menu as seen on the Google Nexus 7 website" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="google nexus 7 menu, css transitions, sidebar, side menu, slide out menu" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css2/component.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css2/demo.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css2/normalize.css' %}" />
    <script src="{% static 'js2/modernizr.custom.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    //...
    //something in here which I dont think is important
    //...
    <header>
            <h1>{% block content %}
            <!-- here comes the main content -->
            {% endblock %}</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Where do I need to search for the problem? If you need more code just ask :)

**EDIT:** I tried analyzing my site with the dev console and the block is coming from this section:

```
.container > header span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 55%;
    color: #74818e;
    padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}
```

How do I override this configuration?

Comment: You can inspect the element in any modern browser (arguably Chrome is a tad more intuitive) and in the opening dev console go to "Computed" side tab. You'll be able to scroll down to `display` property. It will tell you where the current value is set. You'll need to add to your CSS a stronger selector applying to that element, setting the desired value for `display`. Or you could go into the stylesheet currently applying and remove the offending ruleset.

Comment: What makes you think they are *not inline*?

Comment: Note the code you posted doesn't help reproduce the problem. We're therefore unable to help. Rather than posting the source of your markup you should post the resulting markup (right-click > view page source). Replace the snippet in your question with a *runnable* [mcve] reproducing the issue and we'll be able to tell how it can be addressed. You tagged your question `html`, `css` and `javascript`, yet the code you posted is not written in any of those.

Comment: Ok, I found the configuration in my css file, how can I override this setting or edit my html so that only that specific section in span tags is inline?

Comment: Try changing  ` display: block;` to ' display: inline;' and see if it works.